# How Java is Architectural neutral?

Tags: java, cpu-architecture

I read that "Java is architectural neutral because it have the capacity to read the factor key of one processor into the factor of another processor."

Please explain me in detail the above statement?

Comment: I think the answer explains why Java is architecture-neutral, but I have no idea what the rest of the sentence means.  I tried Googling "factor key" and got nothing.

Comment: Where did you read that?  [Edit] a link into your question so we can see the original, because you (or google translate) made a mess of the second half of the sentence.

Answer (score 0):

Java was designed to support applications on networks.
To enable a Java application to execute anywhere on the network, the compiler generates an architecture-neutral object file format--the compiled code is executable on many processors, given the presence of the Java runtime system